# Verify that any subfield of $\mathbb{C} $ must contain every rational number

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is an extract from *Linear Algebra* by *Hoffman and Kunze*:

> The interested reader should verify that any subfield of $\Bbb C$ must contain every rational number.

Here is my own attempt at verifying this:

Let $F$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Let us consider an infinite set $P$ of rational numbers such that the infinite set $F$ and $P$ are disjoint. Take an arbitrary number $\frac{p} {q} $, where $p$ and $q$ are integers, from $P$. This number can be written as follows:

$$\frac{p+z_n} {q} + \frac{-z_n} {q}, $$ where $z_n$ is any integer. Let $a_n= \frac{p+z_n} {q} $ and $b_n= \frac{-z_n} {q}$. It is clear that by adjusting $z_n$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ can be any rational number of choice. Let us pick two such rational numbers $a_1 \in F$ and $b_1 \in F$. We see that $a_1 + b_1 = \frac{p} {q} $. This is absurd, for the definition of a field requires $\frac{p} {q} $ to be in the field $F$. It is therefore required that $\frac{p} {q} $ be in $F$. Since $\frac{p} {q} $ is arbitrary, all elements of $P$ should lie in $F$.

Comment: in the very first line of your proof attempt, do you mean let $F$ be a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I'm sorry. My wording there was misleading. I'll change it.

Comment: As written, $a_n, b_n$ cannot be any rational number of choice: they must have $q$ as their denominator. Moreover, how do you know that $F$ contains any rational numbers at all?

Comment: Hint: any subfield of $\mathbb C$ contains $1$. And hence $1 + 1$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 yes, I was wrong there. I will need to think more about my working after this. Thank you.

Comment: @Mathmo123 got it! 1 is a part of every field. I can form any integer using it and the basic operations. For a non-zero integer in F, there should exist its reciprocal in F. I now have rational numbers of the form 1/z, where z is any non-zero integer. I can go on operating on 1/z to get other rational numbers, thereby making any rational number of my choice. Is my reasoning sound?

Comment: @R004 Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 6):

Let $F$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $x=\frac pq$ be a rational number. We need to see that $x\in F$.

$1\in F$ as is it's a field. Therefore $p=1+1+\cdots +1\in F$. For the same reason, $q=1+1+\cdots +1$ is also part of $F$. And hence $q^{-1}\in F$.

It follows that $x=p\cdot q^{-1}\in F$.

Answer (score 3):

The basic structure of your proof is wrong. You want to prove $\mathbb Q\subseteq F$, but what you actually are trying to do in this proof is show that no infinite subset $P$ of $\mathbb Q$ is in $F^c$. This would not prove $\mathbb Q\subseteq F$, since it could be that all of $\mathbb Q$ is in $F$ except for a finite number of elements.

$a_n$ and $b_n$ cannot be made to equal any pair of rationals, they must have $q$ as a denominator and they must sum to $\frac pq$, which is very restrictive. In particular we can't be sure we can find a $z_n$ to make $a_n$ and $b_n$ be in $F$.